# Debugging WPF browser applications gives a download file

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, debugging, download, xbap

I have built an application for my college work in WPF browser, but when I try to debug, Firefox opens and gives me a download of the xbap file, which should run in the browser. This happens in VS2008 Express and VS2010 beta. I have tried in Internet Explorer and Chrome with the same result. .NET is framework is installed right upto v4.0. This didnt happen before I started using Windows 7, but this shouldn't make much difference, right?
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your MIME type settings in IIS.  In earlier versions of Windows this was somewhat obscure to find in the UI, but in 7 it's easy: Start -> search for IIS -> choose IIS Manager -> filter for MIME.

You need to have the following types configured:

```
MIME Type                        Extension
application/manifest             .manifest
application/x-ms-xbap            .xbap
application/octet-stream         .deploy
application/x-ms-application     .application
application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument   .xps
application/xaml+xml             .xaml
```

(taken from here: http://www.xbap.org/faq.html )

Comment: Well it turns out IIS manager wasn't even enabled in control panel. I have enabled and added those extensions but the problem is still present.

Comment: Then you are probably using Cassini (aka "Visual Studio Web Development Server").  I wouldn't recommend this for a variety of reasons.  Among them, there doesn't appear to be a way to configure its MIME types.  You'll have to configure HttpHandlers directly from web.config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is the problem as it isn't only visual studio which is affected. The demo on http://www.xbap.org/faq.html also does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox runs XBAPs by using a dll from the .Net 3.5 Installer, and since Windows 7 comes with 3.5 already installed, this dll isn't available

Solution is to copy the file `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Windows Presentation Foundation\NPWPF.dll` from an XP machine to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\plugins` (if the plugin folder doesn't exist, create it)